# Pixel Editor disabled in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, pixel

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.4.0 with Windows 10 to edit a few pixels in a raster. I'm creating a map of areas connected to the ocean and there are a few corners of narrow inlets that I need to correct to ensure they connect. The Pixel Editor in the Imagery toolbar is disabled (see picture). I've tried changing the raster format from TIFF to GRID, tried setting the Source Type to "Thematic" or "Elevation", and tried converting from integer to float values. None of that worked, and restarting the program did not work either. Any tricks for getting Pixel Editor to work?

[image]

Comment: Is the  Image Analyst enabled and licensed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pixel Editor is a new tool in the ArcGIS Pro Image Analyst extension with version 2.4

Kindly login to your ArcGIS Online organization and assign the license(image analyst).

1. Sign in to AGOL
2. Navigate to Organizations --> Licenses
3. Find the Image Analyst and assign the license to the user(yourself)
4. Relaunch Pro and check if the pixel editor is enabled

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/image-analyst/pixel-editor-in-arcgis-pro.htm

Comment: Ah, that was the problem. Image Analyst is not available to me through my organization's license. Too bad.